# Comparação de duas curvas

Tags: r

Olá Tenho que seguir uma determinação da RDC 166/2017 da Anvisa e uma das coisas que ela pede é a comparação de duas retas através da inclinação, intercepto e  cálculo de coincidência.
Dos três cálculos só consegui fazer o da coincidência, de acordo com o mostrado abaixo:

```
Comp=read.csv(file="C:/Users/porti/OneDrive/Script/efeito_matriz.csv",sep=";")
Comp

X1<-(Comp$"ï..X1")
X1
Y1<-(Comp$"Y1")
Y1
X2<-(Comp$"X2")
X2
Y2<-(Comp$"Y2")
Y2

x = c(X1, X2) 
y = c(Y1, Y2) 
z = factor(c(rep(1, length(X1)), rep(2, length(X2)))) 
z
C1 = lm(y~x*z) 
C2 = lm(y~x) 
anova(C1, C2)
```

Alguém tem ideia de como faço para comparar o intercepto e a inclinação dessas duas curvas?

Comment: Difícil, sem dados e ao menos sua natureza. Pode atualizar com parte dos dados ou o `summary(x)` e `summary(y)`?

Answer (score 1):

Se fizer

```
summary(C1)
```

terá o resultado parecido:

```
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  9.72936    0.58273   16.70   <2e-16 ***
#   x            2.01814    0.02864   70.47   <2e-16 ***
#   z           10.47969    0.74020   14.16   <2e-16 ***
#   x:z          0.96228    0.03382   28.45   <2e-16 ***
```

Indica que o intercepto para o segundo caso X2 seria (9,72 + 10,47) e sua diferença é significativa. O mesmo pode ser feito para a inclinação, para X2 caso seria (2,02 + 0,96) também significativa, isso com dados simulados.

Pode ver isso em um gráfico:

```
plot(y~x, col=z)
abline(a=9.72936,b=2.01814,col=3)
abline(a=9.72936+10.47969,b=2.01814+0.96228,col=4)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode verificar isso fazendo:

```
X1a=c(X1,rep(0, length(X2)))
X2a=c(rep(0,length(X1)),X2)
c3=lm(y~0+z+X1a+X2a)
summary(c3)
car::linearHypothesis(c3,"1*z1 - 1*z2 = 0")
car::linearHypothesis(c3,"1*X1a - 1*X2a = 0")
```

Comment: Devia incluir a geração dos dados simulados, de preferência com uma chamada a `set.seed`. Sem isso a resposta, que parece ser boa, não é reprodutível.